# SQL ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY error1064

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, alter-table

For some reason my sql script fails on adding the primary key statement. I was wondering if anyone could explain why ?

Here is the table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_bwg_album` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `preview_image` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `random_preview_image` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `order` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `author` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is the stement it fails on -

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_bwg_album`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Also related to the table is this final statement.

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_bwg_album`
MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I confused as what the problem is, the SQL is a dump from a my live server. I am just updating my development server at home. using MySql workbench I get the standard 1064 error.

> 16:58:40  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD PRIMARY KEY
>   (`id`)' at line 1 0.000 sec

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is working on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/baf8f)

Comment: Is `wp_bwg_album` an empty table? If it isn't, do you have any duplicate values in `id`?

Comment: I can't see anything in the syntax that would stop it from executing also. I'm a little confused to be honest. Is there any setting's in the database type that could cause this ?

Comment: Just double checked its a  blank table with no inserts, has an auto increment added at the end of the script for 'id'.

Comment: What strikes me as odd is that, before "Error Code: 1064", your error message begins "[timestamp] ADD PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)".  Where has that come from?  Is your MySQL client suggesting to you that ``ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)`` is the entire command that it has received and in which a syntax error has been detected?  If so, the error makes perfect sense and is probably explained by unexpected/premature termination/execution of the first part of the command `ALTER TABLE \`wp_bwg_album\``, with the second part ``ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)`` treated as a second, separate command.

Comment: Also I notice that you have tagged this question [tag:sql-server]—was that by mistake?

Comment: "*has an auto increment added at the end of the script for 'id'*"—what does that mean? Please show it in your question.

Comment: I test your query at mysql 5.6.24 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_bwg_album`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `pk_wp_bwg_album` PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

The constraint name can be anyone.

Comment: Well that helped as I now get the error >17:31:16 ALTER TABLE `wp_bwg_album`     ADD CONSTRAINT `pk_wp_bwg_album` PRIMARY KEY (`id`) Error Code: 1068. Multiple primary key defined 0.000 sec

Comment: Try this add pk with create table query
CREATE TABLE table-name(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

Comment: So then you may have declared a primary key before. Try to do it all again and try my solution, if not work try to create a new table with the primary key definiton.

Comment: Yes but no mention of a Primary Key before that statement. I may have taken the dump incorrectly from my c Panel I will recheck those settings.

Comment: Check this but if still don't work try create the table again with Primary key definition like @Massod Rehman said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
alter table wp_bwg_album
add constraint pk_id primary key(id)
```